# Copy a list of objects to another typed list in one line of code

Tags: c#, linq, coding-style

I have a `List` of `MyType1` objects. I want to copy all these objects in a new `List` of `MyType2` objects, having a constructor for `MyType2` that takes a `MyType1` object as argument.

For now, I do it this way:

```
List<MyType1> type1objects = new List<MyType1>();
// Fill type1objects
// ...
List<MyType2> type2objects = new List<MyType2>();
foreach (MyType1 type1obj in type1objects) {
    MyType2 type2obj = new MyType2(type1obj);
    type2objects.Add(type2obj);
}
```

Is there a way to do this one-line (I'm thinking maybe it is possible with Linq)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var type2objects = type1objects.Select(o => new MyType2(o)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple projection using `Select()` with Linq, then make a list out of this enumeration using `ToList()`:

```
var type2objects = type1objects.Select( x => new MyType2(x))
                               .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var type2objects = type1objects.Select(type1obj => new MyType2(type1obj)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
List<MyType2> list2 = new List<MyType2>(list1.Select(x => new MyType2(x)));
```

Comment: The first line of code you wrote before your edits didn't compile (I didn't vote you down though).

Comment: Yea, before reading further I thought `MyType1` could be cast to `MyType2`. I posted an edit pretty quickly though, so I'm not sure why I received the second downvote.

Answer (score 0):

If you just copy all elements from list1 to list2 you will **not** get true copies of those elements. You will just have another list with the same elements!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
List<MyType2> type2objects = new List<MyType2>();
type2objects.AddRange(type1objects.Select(p => new MyType2(p)));
```

In this way you can even preserve the values contained in `type2objects`.

I'll add that you know the size of `type1objects`, so you can speedup a little:

```
List<MyType2> type2objects = new List<MyType2>(type1objects.Count);
```

Here the capacity of `type2objects` is pre-setted.

or, if you are re-using an "old2" `type2objects`

```
if (type2objects.Capacity < type1objects.Count + type2objects.Count)
{
    type2objects.Capacity = type1objects.Count + type2objects.Count;
}
```

In this way you know the `List` won't need intermediate resizes.

Someone will call this premature optimization, and it is. But you *could* need it.

Answer (score 0):

You might also get some mileage out of Convert.ChangeType() depending on what you're converting:

```
List<MyType2> type2objects = type1objects.Select(
    type1object => Convert.ChangeType(type1object, typeof(MyType2))
    ).ToList();
```